# How to override or.apache.http in Android platform

Tags: android, intellij-idea, apache-httpcomponents

I have wrote an Android application that uses HttpComponents from Apache to make a connection to server.

The version I used is 4.3 (newest), everything is ok, except when running.

I got exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.<in
it>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:487)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConne
ctionManager.java:147)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConne
ctionManager.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConne
ctionManager.java:112)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at net.xnano.weatherlife.util.ApacheHTTP.<init>(ApacheHTTP.java:97)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at net.xnano.weatherlife.view.WeatherLifeActivity$3.<init>(WeatherLifeActivity.java:105)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at net.xnano.weatherlife.view.WeatherLifeActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(WeatherLifeActivity.j
ava:105)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:980)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:547)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConne
ctionFactory.java:72)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConne
ctionFactory.java:84)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<clinit>(ManagedHttpClientCon
nectionFactory.java:59)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        ... 25 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFac
tory.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFac
tory.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<clinit>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterF
actory.java:46)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1699):        ... 28 more
```

The library (in jar archive) which I added to libs folder has been exported, it seems the application uses internal org.apache.http package instead of my own library.

The IDE is Intellij Idea.

Did anyone solve this issue before please help me?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is presented a few times in SO. The solution I took was to use a repackaged version of the library called [httpclientandroidlib](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/). This was presented as a solution in a newer version of this question at [How to Override Android Api Class with a class available in added jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836012/how-to-override-android-api-class-with-a-class-available-in-added-jar)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own library in next way

```
com.yourlibrary.MyClass myClass= new com.yourlibrary.MyClass();
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm talking about org.apache.http class.

My project has HttpComponents in libs/ (httpclient.jar, httpcore.jar...). And Android platform has such classes in its. When I run application, it will look for class inside platform instead of jar(s) in my libs/ directory.