# How to Override Android Api Class with a class available in added jar?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apache

***Scenario :*** An android project say, ProjAndroid refers a java project say(HelperProj).

In HelperProj, I tried to use httpConnection Pooling by instantiating its manager.

`PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();`

I came across [Apache example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) and was able to implement as a standalone program without any glitches.

But with android, first it gave error as `NoClassDefFoundError` which was resolved when I added *httpclient-4.3.1.jar* and *httpcore-4.3.jar* even to android project.But now I am getting another Error

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE`

***My Conclusion:-***
The above field should be [available](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3-beta2/org/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter.java?av=f) in httpcore-4.3.jar as I did not get any error when I ran my code as standalone.So,I searched and found that android already provides [BasicLineFormatter class](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter.html) where this field is not available and may be at runtime this class is referred.

> please correct me in case the above is wrong.

***Help:-***
So someone please guide me as how may I resolve this resource conflict and use the class available in jar instead of the one available with android api.

Comment: get the file and embed into your code, as ultimate solution :) You can read more about this as "dll hell"

Comment: i thought of it but I don't want to do it as it will become android specific..I wanted to write code such that I can use it for other java applications too..

Answer (score 5):

> So someone please guide me as how may I resolve this resource conflict and use the class available in jar instead of the one available with android api.

This is not directly possible. You do not have control over the classpath, and firmware-loaded classes always take precedence as a result.

You are welcome to try to use [utilities like `jarjar`](http://jarjar.googlecode.com/) to move the third-party code into a separate package.

Or, you can see if somebody else has already done this for you, [as with htpclientandroid](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/).

Or, you are welcome to come up with a different solution to your problem that does not involve replacing Android-supplied classes.

Comment: What worked perfectly for me is the [httpclientandroid](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/) solution you provided. thanks!